How does the rabbit ears antenna work?
How do I built a rabbit ears antenna?
I would like to know how a rabbit ears antenna work, like the one shown in the picture below.

From:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_antenna#/media/File:Rabbit-ears_dipole_antenna_with_UHF_loop_20090204.jpg
I need to know how much length the two whip antennas have, and how much gap should there be between them to make them work as a dipole antenna?
Also, how is the loop length is calculated for such a single loop UHF antenna?
How are all the three antennas connected in this rabbit ears antenna?

Hi! So, you added a new question "How do rabbit ears antenna work?" to your previous question, which was already closed because it doesn't contain enough info. So, because you've not fixed any of the problems with your two previous questions in this question, this can only be closed again. Thus, to avoid that, I'd just go ahead and delete all the things you should have fixed and keep your one, new question, "how does it work" (which is different than "how do I build one"). But honestly, the answer would be long and not very helpful for building one, because you'd still have to do all

the math, simulation, testing and design iteration yourself. I don't think that's what you want. So, can you please, instead of posting a third question, fix your second question? Voting to close this as a duplicate of that.

Oh you just 20 minutes ago closed https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/22835/how-do-i-built-a-rabbit-ears-antenna. Too bad, then I'll just have to judge this question on its own, it's missing all the details needed to assist you in constructing. Also, we asked for these details, in depth, on that deleted question, so you can look these criteria up yourself. I'm stopping to spend time on this.

@MarcusMüller I just tried to clarify it.

@MikeWaters so, is this question about building one, or about the theory of operation? If it's about building, my request for specifications still stands. If it's about theory of operation, we'll need to know a bit more about where the asker is stuck in modelling – I can't write a book on everything, from transmission line theory over Maxwell to antenna theory; this is a complex composite antenna as I tried to point out multiple times, so the way one could explain a half-wavelength dipole won't work.

@MikeWaters furthermore, the question "how is it internally connected" is also already answered in this question, which does come up as one of the top three related questions; maybe that helps the asker? By the way, the answer there also highlights that there's not one length (just as my answer to the asker's first question did) to design for :) I honestly think that at this level of addressing the questions we ask, we really can't help much.

I'm sure I wouldn't (and neither would others) mind answering counter-questions. For example when I ask for frequency ranges more narrowly defined than "UHF", a "how do I figure this out? I just want to do XYZ" would have been most welcome. But: Instead of helping us helping them, this user hops to new questions. And then, still addresses nothing. So, nope. Not gonna sink more time in this state of question.

@Dereck I really cannot understand how you do not realize that the way you word your comments is incredibly offensive and unkind.  Please take this as your final warning.

@Dereck I will look to chat with you in the next few days to clear up any misunderstandings about why it is not ok to post a comment that says, "You are too stupid to understand."

Because the question is lacking specifics, this answer is lacking specifics.

I need to know how much length the two whip antennas have, and how much gap should there be between them to make them work as a dipole antenna?

The appropriate length is frequency dependent, so you should choose a length that is appropriate for the frequency that you are looking to receive.
The gap should be as small as practical. I have no idea of the appropriateness of the antenna to your need since you omit it. Suffice it to say that it's not critical and shouldn't be high up on a list of concerns for any practical antenna build.

How are all the three antennas connected in this rabbit ears antenna?

In my experience, the VHF and UHF antennas are connected via separate transmission lines to the TV. The VHF using coax and an F-style connector (IIRC) and the UHF using twin-lead and a balun. Or maybe the other way around. you can google to figure which is which.
The rabbit ears are 2 elements of a single VHF antenna (yes, a dipole!), one of which is connected to the shield of the coax transmission line, the other of which is connected to the center conductor.
Each end of the UHF loop is connected to one of the twin-lead wires.
I'm sorry there isn't more to share here, but that's mainly a result of the vagueness of the question.

Thank you for answering my question. I don't have much details about the antenna to give and  that's why my question also doesn't have much details. But someone told me that the two whip antennas work as a dipole antenna, and the gap between the feed point should be between 1-2 cm. Is that true? I need to know how to calculate the length/circumference of the UHF antenna based of the frequency?

Let's start with some basics. Are you asking because you're trying to accomplish something or because you have an academic interest? Is this for reception only or also for transmit?

@user10897549 and "I don't have much details to give": then try to give us what you have. What are you going to use this for? I swear, I'm not asking to annoy you, and we're not a judgy crowd, but if you don't know which frequencies within the UHF band you're using an antenna for, you simply don't get to build that antenna. you must figure out.

@user10897549, I see you posted a question asking specifically about the gap at a dipole feed point. Can I ask, how did you come to be so focused on this particular aspect of the antenna? It's typically a very minor, non-critical aspect of construction, and to have such focus on it is rare.
